# How to: watchkit button displays image at url in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uiimage, watchkit

I want a button press in Watchkit to display an image from a URL.  Given there's no UIWebView in Watchkit, my assumption is that I will need to trigger via the watch button, the loading of a UIWebView for the URL on the phone, store in an UIImage, that I can pass back to the watch to display.  First is that the best strategy, secondly can anyone help me with the code for storing a UIImage from UIWebView in Swift?

Phone's ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var URLPath = "myURL.jpeg"


    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadAddressURL()

    }

    //to fit webpage within webView
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        webView.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        webView.center = self.view.center
        webView.scalesPageToFit = true
    }

    func loadAddressURL () {
        let url = NSURL(string: URLPath)
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
    }


}
```

Comment: Why not just download the image directly? Why do you need a web view at all?

Comment: Maybe I'm overthinking it then, with what's available in Watchkit, what can I call on WKInterfaceImage, i.e. setImage or setImageData? that I can set to a url.image?  I'm probably in a knowledge gap here...

Comment: You can't set a WKInterfaceImage directly from a URL. You were partially correct. You can initiate the download on the phone and then transfer the image data to the Watch.

Comment: Yes, I need to figure out how to pass the image data to the watch

Comment: Take a look at the docs for `openParentApplication:reply:`. You can kick off a request to the host app, download the image, and send it back in the reply. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WKInterfaceController/openParentApplication:reply: